# List iteration on python with mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, list, python-2.7

I am working on a small python project where I need to create a mongodb entry.

This is the list of values you received from another collection:

```
["India", "Australia", "South Africa"]
```

So the above list contains three items. What I want from my next collection is:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('some id'),
"name": "Player",
"value": "India"
}

{
"_id": ObjectId('some id'),
"name": "Player",
"value": "Australia"
}

{
"_id": ObjectId('some id'),
"name": "Player",
"value": "South Africa"
}
```

I only want the list of values to be added in the value key but the name should be constant. It should repeat again and again but the value key will be changed based on number entries in the list.

How do I approach this problem in python?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share a basic snippet of your code to make helping you easier.

Comment: this is from player collection "name" : "Player" "value": ["India", "Aus", "SA"]. I tried basic coding like getting the document from the db and so on. No clue on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can apparoch this issue in different ways. A very basic one would be using list comprehensions like this:

```
values_list = ["India", "Australia", "South Africa"]
names_list = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"]


def create_objects(name, values):
    # this returns a list of dicts basically and should be adopted to create 'real' mongoDB objects/entries
    return [{"_id": "some id", "name": name, "value": value} for value in values]


objects = [create_objects(name, values_list) for name in names_list]
print(objects)
```

Another way is to calculate all possible combinations (called product in itertools) before-hand to prevent the two interating for-loops

```
from itertools import product

objects = [{"_id": "some id", "name": name, "value": value} for name, value in product(names_list, values_list)]
print(objects)
```